# X-ray frequency or crystal structure: which was known first?

Tags: history, x-ray-crystallography

In the classical Bragg setup, one can determine the distance between crystal layers if the wavelength of a characteristic line is known or the other way round, calculate the distance if the wavelength of a x-ray line is known.

Which quantity was determined first and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a long time there were the x-ray units of length of which the relation to the meter was not known with high accuracy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_unit

The coupling was achieved using high-order diffraction from mechanically ruled gratings.

At grazing incidence, a ruled grating can give diffraction for wavelengths that are much shorter than the wavelength of the radiation. See for example [Schawlow's experiment](https://www.nsta.org/publications/news/story.aspx?id=49599) using the millimeter marks.

This can also be done with a diffraction grating made by a mechanical ruling machine, like the ones that Rowland made. The ruling distance can be measured quite accurately (for example by diffraction of visible light with a known wavelength). From that one can then measure the wavelength of a characteristic emission line of some element that is also suitable for x-ray diffraction.

Comment: "definition was [...] made in terms of the spacing between planes of the calcite crystals". Doesn't seem to answer the question :(
Can you elaborate on the mechanical gratings?

Comment: Gratings for x-ray or visible light?

Comment: @Jasper The trick is to use the same grating for both.

Comment: I'm so going to try the Schawlow experiment!
Final question: don't the x-rays penetrate the grating easily? Or is it "thick" enough for bragg scattering to occur?

Comment: At grazing incidence, reflectivity goes up (Fresnel equations). In the x-ray range, one can even get total _external_ reflectivity because the index of refraction of materials is slightly smaller than unity for x-rays.